# Can you paralyze a skeleton?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency

I have skeleton enemy in my game and a paralyze(stun) stat. Can you paralyze an un-living creature? According to my research, paralysis is related to the nervous system, so a skeleton shouldn't have a nervous system. What mechanism would a realistic (science-based) paralysis system use that would allow paralysis of living and non-living things? No (with an explanation) is acceptable.

Comment: It's magic so anything goes.

Comment: According to (hard) science skeletons do not move at all. They just crumble when left alone

Comment: Do you have a science-based mechanism for animating the skeleton?

Comment: As far as I know, it takes powerful magic to animate a skeletonmand make it do something - of its own will or remotely controlled by others.  So simply removing the spells should deanimate the skeleton, and weakening the spells enough could make the skeleton stop moving.

Comment: Generally speaking, it's considered very bad form to award the green checkmark within one or two days of asking a question. (Mind you, I agree that it's a really good answer!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No**

Language won't allow it. The term "paralizing" always refers to living entities, it cannot be applied to dead objects because the don't actively "feel" or "sense" anything. There is no science-based way you can paralyze something not experiencing a life nervous system.

Objects can be *immobilized*.

There is a real world method to immobilize a skeleton, often applied. That is leave it in peace.

A known magic way to immobilize a moving skeleton is: kill the wizard that made it move. I could refer to a well known recent fantasy series.. last episode.. but that would be against the rules of WB, so I won't.

Comment: The idea that killing a wizard will cause all their active spells to stop working seems highly lazy & unrealistic, even in fantasy.  More likely the wizard would be the only person capable of turning off the spell.  There was a story by Isaac Asimov "The up-To-Date Sorceror" where a love potion caused people to fall in love against their will, like in the Gilbert & Sullivan operetta "The Sorceror".  In the operetta the death of the sorceror ended the spell, but in Asimov's story the characters found that the original ending was for everyone to get married, because "marriage kills love".

Comment: @M.A.Golding agree. As we're citing titles now, the series I referred to was Game of Thrones. In order to avoid a lazy answer, we'd need a lot more information about how skeletons have started to move in the first place and how they manage to keep moving. To paralyze a skeleton, the method would be to inhibit any movement *again*. As the movement had a magical cause, something magical should happen to stop it ?

Answer (score 4):

**Spiderman style.**

[image: skeleton with web]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QvSIpsHaUkw

If you paralyze something by wrapping it up in fibers or goo, that should work for anything corporeal and solid.  Strong foes can wiggle around and bust loose shortly.  Weak foes stay stuck.

Comment: In terms of most (table-top) game mechanics, there is a difference between being restrained and paralysed. Webs sound more like restraint than paralysis.

Comment: @LioElbammalf - agreed.  A restrained skeleton could still do some loud jaw clacking.